# HTML5 Android Phonegap Web application offline cache manifest

Tags: android, html, cordova, cache-manifest

My application not save dbtest.xml and not read when wi-fi turn off.
It is file CordovaApp.java

```
package io.cordova.hellocordova;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
public class CordovaApp extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        this.appView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        this.appView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 15);  
        String appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
        this.appView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
        this.appView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        this.appView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
}
```

On server I add files .manifest, .htaccess and dbtext.xml
.manifest look that:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# Wersja 0.3
# Jawnie buforowane wpisy
dbtest.xml
# All other resources (e.g. sites) require the user to be online.
NETWORK:
*
```

.htaccess look that:

```
<mime-mapping>
<extension>manifest</extension>
<mime-type>text/cache-manifest</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

And my PhoneGap application not work offline. What i do wrong? I must add some text in other files? What i have to do ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Although PhoneGap is an offline solution where the HTML, CSS and JS files etc are held in the assets/www folder within the app, there are some cases where you might want the app to point to a remote server where the HTML5 file and its CSS/JS are located. They can be downloaded onto your device and ran as offline files when the device has no Internet connection.
  [Click Here for techniques](http://tmkmobile.wordpress.com/2012/03/04/html5-offline-solution/)

Comment: Previously already done everything according to the instructions on the page. The application works on wi-fi is turned off for 10 minutes sometimes for an hour sometimes offline. The data is then disappear. What could be the cause?